# Question about the notations $\delta_{n,0}$ and $\delta_{0,k}$

Tags: combinatorics, notation, generating-functions

I refer to [generatingfunctionology](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/gfology2.pdf).

On page 94, I see the use of $\delta_{n,0}$:

\begin{align*}
mh(n,m) &= \sum_{r,m'\ge 1} h(n-rm', m-m')d_r & (n,m\ge 1; h(n,0) =\delta_{n,0})
\end{align*}

Similarly, on page 100, I see the use of $\delta_{0,k}$:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n,k\ge 0} p(n,k)x^ny^k &= \frac{1}{(1-yx)(1-yx^2)(1-yx^3)(1-yx^4)\cdots} \\
& (p(0,k) = \delta_{0,k}).
\end{align*}

Both $\delta_{n,0}$ and $\delta_{0,k}$ don't seem to be defined in the book.

Is this a common notation?  What (constant) values do $\delta_{n,0}$ and $\delta_{0,k}$ represent?

Comment: My gut instinct is usually that it refers to the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).

Comment: I think you are right!  Thanks!